# Update Gtk Label text in a loop without changing Window with Python

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I would like to change the Gtk Label text with each countdown second without destroying the MainWindow frame. This can be found in the countdown function. All suggestions are kindly welcomed.

```
#from cProfile import label
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk 
import datetime
import time


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Timer")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_size_request(200,100)
        self.vbox_right = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=8)
        self.add(self.vbox_right)

        self.fr_label = Gtk.Label()
        self.vbox_right.pack_start(self.fr_label, True, True, 0)
   
    
def countdown(total_seconds):
    win = MainWindow()
    while total_seconds > 0:
        #win = MainWindow()
        timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)
        win.fr_label.set_text(str(timer))
        win.vbox_right.pack_start(win.fr_label, True, True, 0)
        win.show_all()
        time.sleep(1)
        total_seconds -= 1
        print('Done')
        win.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
    

window = countdown(5)
#window.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
#window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and how did it not work as you had hoped?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix 2 things.

First, when updating a label with `set_text()`, you don't need to "re-pack" it like you do with this line in your `countdown()` method,

```
win.vbox_right.pack_start(win.fr_label, True, True, 0)
```

This causes an error, as you're trying to set a parent to a widget that already has a parent.

Second, if your program is performing some action that takes time, like in your case waiting for 1 second, with `time.sleep(1)`, you need to make sure it does so outside the main event loop. Otherwise, this wait event will block the main loop. This is explained here, https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html

For your example, there are 2 options. You can either use python's `threading` module, which I find to be the better, more general solution, or you can use the `GLib` API, specifically, `GLib.timeout_add()` or `GLib.timeout_add_seconds()`.

## Threading

For threading you need to first import `threading` and then create a `Thread` instance object that will run the task your GUI program needs to run in the background. You also need a target function to pass to the `Thread` when you create it, along with any arguments you want to pass to your target function. It's best to make the `Thread` a daemon thread so that once your main loop quits, the `Thread` will automatically stop as well. In your target function, you need to use `GLib.idle_add()`, to perform any tasks that you want to take place inside the main loop, for example updating a label. Without using this API, the label will never update. Anyway, here's how it would work:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import datetime
import time
import threading

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Timer")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_size_request(200,100)
        self.vbox_right = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=8)
        self.add(self.vbox_right)
        self.fr_label = Gtk.Label()
        self.vbox_right.pack_start(self.fr_label, True, True, 0)
        self.show_all()

def update_label(label, text):
    label.set_text(text)

def countdown(total_seconds):
    while total_seconds >= 0:
        timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)
        GLib.idle_add(update_label, win.fr_label, str(timer))
        win.show_all()
        time.sleep(1)
        total_seconds -= 1
        print('timer', timer)
    else:
        print("Done")

win = MainWindow()
win.show_all()
thread = threading.Thread(daemon=True, target=countdown, args=[5])
thread.start()
win.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

Output:

```
timer 0:00:04
timer 0:00:03
timer 0:00:02
timer 0:00:01
timer 0:00:00
Done
```

## GLib.timeout_add()

In this case, you are letting `GLib` handle the threading for you, and it will call your target function at "regular" intervals until the target function returns `False`. I put regular in quotes because it does not guarantee precise timing. You can read more about it here: https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GLib-2.0/functions.html#GLib.timeout_add

Here's how this example would look:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import datetime
import time

class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, timer):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Timer")
        self.timer = timer
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_size_request(200,100)
        self.vbox_right = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=8)
        self.add(self.vbox_right)
        self.fr_label = Gtk.Label()
        self.fr_label.set_text(str(timer))
        self.vbox_right.pack_start(self.fr_label, True, True, 0)
        self.show_all()

def countdown(win):
    timer = win.timer
    if timer.seconds > 0:
        timer -= datetime.timedelta(seconds = 1)
        win.timer = timer
        win.fr_label.set_text(str(timer))
        print("timer", str(timer))
        return True
    else:
        print("Done")
        return False

timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 5)
win = MainWindow(timer)
win.connect("delete-event",Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
GLib.timeout_add_seconds(1, countdown, win)
Gtk.main()
```

Output:

```
timer 0:00:04
timer 0:00:03
timer 0:00:02
timer 0:00:01
timer 0:00:00
Done
```

As you can, see each method differs slightly in the implementation, and it depends on what your task is to determine which option is best. There is a third, but ultimately more convoluted option described in
https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html which involves using the `Gio` API and it's `async` implementation.

Comment: Your answer was very insightful and well-written. I am a few months late but I still appreciate your help

Comment: @RawleyAmankwah thanks for letting me know. Would you mind accepting the answer if it was helpful